# How to use have a IEnumerable<MyType> in a Route Attribute with Web Api 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

What do I put in the constructor of the route attribute in this scenario? If you know of an article discussing this could you post me a link?

```
[RoutePrefix("api/MyApi")]
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    //What goes in here?
    [Route("")]
    public HttpStatusCode EditPermissions(IEnumerable<MyType> myTypes)
    {
        //stuff
    }

}
```

I am basing this information on [this article.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario you would not put the data it in the route since that would make the URL look terrible and would be unflexible(also not possible with your example).

In your case I would for example simply name this route "edit-permission".

```
    [HttpPut, Route("edit-permission")] // The URL is then /api/MyApi/edit-permissions
    public IHttpActionResult EditPermissions([FromBody]IEnumerable<MyType> myTypes)
    {
        // Do stuff with myTypes
        return Ok("Editing permissions was a success!"); // Returns a 200 HTTP status code
    }
```

If you put the types in the http request body instead of the URL and use the IHttpActionResult(or HttpResponseMessage) type in your controllers, the WebApi framework will automatically map the body to the myTypes attribute.

Comment: Is this the normal / best practice for dealing with Collection Parameters?

Comment: Can't comment on whether it's best practice but judging from your question it looks to me to be the most practical solution. You can add new parameters to the body as needed without having to change the URL every time. If you wanted to do this by putting it in the URL it would look like "/api/action?param1=x&param2=x2&param3=x3&param4=x4" and all of those parameters would have to be arguments in the action definition. Having a couple of parameters in URL is fine but once you have a collection of them it becomes much cleaner and easier to maintain if it's done the way i described.